# Intuit Ipp Blue Dot Menu Location Issue

Tags: css, intuit-partner-platform

I would like to control where the blue dot menu appears in my application.

By default it is located on the upper right corner of the web browser which is fine but it looks like it is part of the browser not my application. I don't want to move it much, I just want to make it look like it is part of the application not the browser.

Is there a way to manually control where the blue dot menu is located?

Comment: I actually was able to move the blue dot menu inside the header using css. I added "position: relative;" into the css class that the blue dot menu is in. This moved the menu down into the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot control the location of the blue dot menu but you can add a background colored css to highlight it.

Comment: That's too bad.

It would be nice to have some control over it so it looks like part of the application not an external menu control.

Comment: Yeah, many developers asked for it but considering our review guidelines, you cannot do that. We want to be consistent in our widgets display across all small business apps.

Comment: Well nimisha, it is possible to control where the blue dot menu shows in your application. I found that using css makes it possible to move it. My blue dot menu is inside a couple of css classes ("body" and "header"). 
Inside the "header" css class I put in:
position: relative;
This moved the position of the blue dot menu down into the application window so it's not just hanging out on the top of the browser window. I wasn't able to do anything else with it but now it  looks like it's part of my application.

Comment: Derrick good to know that but you might to confirm if that's ok with the technical/security review team. Please drop a support ticket and our security review team will confirm https://developer.intuit.com/docs/9_other_resources/0030_support. Attach the screenshots as well.